# right-click on touchpad not showing menu

Tags: touchpad, right-click

Laptop - Acer aspire ES 15  - MODEL- ES1-521-62EC - WINS 10

Hi,

i cannot right-click on any link to open in a new tab. it just opens the link
instead of showing a menu with options.

This is a new laptop and i upgraded wins 7 to wins 10.

I have tried different browsers - firefox and edge, but same result.

Please help.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Does right-clicking on anything else bring up the proper menu?  Your trackpad might be broken and sending left-clicks instead of right-clicks.  If you hold control down and click on the link, it should open in a new tab.

Answer (score 0):

Your right-click is somehow bound to middle-click. If you are right-clicking on links, and in all browsers, it is simply opening the link in a new tab, then it is producing a middle-click.

Look at any software you have that manages keyboard input.

edit: middle-click meaning scroll-wheel click